# How to format default help command

Tags: discord.py

Can someone please tell me how to format the Default help command in discord.py
I already know how to change the description however,  I want to be able to change the width and sort them alphabetically.

Thanks for any help
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override certain functions in the default help command. Below is an official example on how to set this up initially:

```
class MyHelpCommand(commands.MinimalHelpCommand):
    def get_command_signature(self, command):
        return '{0.clean_prefix}{1.qualified_name} {1.signature}'.format(self, command)

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self._original_help_command = bot.help_command
        bot.help_command = MyHelpCommand()
        bot.help_command.cog = self

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.bot.help_command = self._original_help_command
```

The example above overrides the implementation of `get_command_signature`.

As you can see, you're supposed to create a new `HelpCommand` class and change the functions. Stuff that you don't want to change can just be left untouched, you don't have to copy-paste the existing code in there.

To see what a `HelpCommand` and `MinimalHelpCommand` can do (to override the methods), I suggest scrolling through the relevant [API Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#help-commands).

This way, in case there's something that you don't like about the default help, you can just change it's behaviour and fix it yourself. In your case, you're gonna want to sort the list of commands before adding them to the codeblock.

I recommend flicking through the default implementation's functions to see what you have to change about it. In your case, `send_bot_help`, `send_cog_help`, `send_command_help`, and `send_group_help` will need the lists sorted.